# Bundler error: builtin_gem? when deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Following this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

When I attempt `git push heroku master` I encounter the following error:

> /tmp/build_50f24046-6d63-4f42-8238-f4cc4b983d77/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:299:in `builtin_gem?': undefined method`include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: can you post the whole log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It appears to be an issue with bundler 1.6.x and cached gems. The next release (1.6.2) is supposed to fix it. I don't know if there's a way to work around it on herkou in the mean time.

I just got the same:

```
git push heroku
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 53, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
Writing objects: 100% (53/53), 2.03 MiB | 606 KiB/s, done.
Total 53 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.1
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Using rake 10.1.1
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing creole 0.3.6
       Installing expression_parser 0.9.0
       Installing asciidoctor 0.1.4
       Installing github-markup 1.1.0
       Installing rubypants 0.2.0
       Installing posix-spawn 0.3.8
       Using rack 1.5.2
       Installing rdoc 3.8
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using bundler 1.6.1
       Installing wikicloth 0.8.0.github.e2deea9
       Installing org-ruby 0.8.1
       Installing rack-protection 1.5.3
       Installing sinatra 1.4.5
       Installing RedCloth 4.2.9.c208bfe
       Installing github-markdown 0.6.5
       Updating files in vendor/cache
       Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
       troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
       /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:299:in `builtin_gem?': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:133:in `cache'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:114:in `block in cache'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:112:in `cache'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:77:in `run'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:146:in `install'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:9:in `start'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/bin/bundle:20:in `block in '
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/bin/bundle:20:in `'
       from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
       from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `'
       Bundler Output: Using rake 10.1.1
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing creole 0.3.6
       Installing expression_parser 0.9.0
       Installing asciidoctor 0.1.4
       Installing github-markup 1.1.0
       Installing rubypants 0.2.0
       Installing posix-spawn 0.3.8
       Using rack 1.5.2
       Installing rdoc 3.8
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using bundler 1.6.1
       Installing wikicloth 0.8.0.github.e2deea9
       Installing org-ruby 0.8.1
       Installing rack-protection 1.5.3
       Installing sinatra 1.4.5
       Installing RedCloth 4.2.9.c208bfe
       Installing github-markdown 0.6.5
       Updating files in vendor/cache
       Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
       troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
       /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:299:in `builtin_gem?': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:133:in `cache'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:114:in `block in cache'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:112:in `cache'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:77:in `run'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:146:in `install'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:9:in `start'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/bin/bundle:20:in `block in '
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
       from /tmp/build_00f7042a-7935-45b2-be31-7f0739e3af93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.1/bin/bundle:20:in `'
       from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
       from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:gh-markup.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gh-markup.git'
```

Comment: FYI, it looks like Heroku found out about this and rolled back Bundler to an old version: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/451

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue. Clearing out vendor/cache fixed it, although the deploy took significantly longer. Hopefully Bundler 1.6.2 will be out soon!